# explanation for the illegal instruction when eax is zero

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, reverse-engineering

```
xor eax,eax
mov [eax], edx
```

This is referred as illegal. Can I get an explanation for this?

Comment: It is not as such illegal but running under an everyday OS using default settings the memory address zero is not mapped to catch NULL pointer references. In real mode you can easily execute that, or under linux after you change `mmap_min_addr` setting and map that page. You could also change `ds` to something that has an address zero mapped (e.g. TLS).

Answer (score 7):

It's not *illegal* per-se.  It can't cause a `#UD` undefined-instruction exception.  That's what "illegal instruction" means in assembly language / machine-code terminology.

Running it in a normal 32-bit program under a normal OS will result in an invalid `#PF` exception (because the zero page won't be mapped).  An OS like Linux will deliver a SIGSEGV to the process, not SIGILL.

As @Jester says, under Linux you could change the `vm.mmap_min_addr` sysctl (https://wiki.debian.org/mmap_min_addr), like WINE needs to run 16-bit Windows programs, then it would be possible to `mmap` that page and run those instructions without faulting.